writebarno not working for specific font in musixtex
It is needed to configure the font of writebarno. The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[border=8pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{Soy pe-rua-na, soy li-me-ña; soy pe-rua-na, soy li-me-ña; !`Ca-ram-ba! soy la}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
\parindent7mm
\sepbarrules
%\smallmusicsize
\instrumentnumber{2}
\setinterinstrument{1}{12pt}%espacio entre Voz y Piano
%\setinterinstrument{2}{12pt}
\interstaff{12}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
\staffbotmarg7\Interligne% set verticle space in one staff score
\setclef16
\setclef{2}{\treble}
\setname2{Voz}
\setname1{Pno}
\setstaffs12
\setstaffs21
%\nobarnumbers
%\nostartrule
\def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
%\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
%\scale{0.03}%
\startbarno=13%
\smallmusicsize
\startpiece%\addspace{0.3\afterruleskip}% 
\A\assignlyrics2{Letras}
\notes\zcharnote{-18}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (pointA) at (0,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
\node (pointB) at (2.6,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V7}}};
\node (pointC) at (8.3,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
\draw[red-undar,thick, line width=0.8mm] (pointA) -- (pointB) -- (pointC) -- (10.7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}\zcn{d}{\A C}\ibu0J3\zq{C}\qb0{J}|\ds&\qp\en%
\notes\ds|\zqu{ce}\cu{g}&\en%
\notes\tbu0\zq{L}\qb0{N}|\ds&\ds\en%
\notes\ds|\zqu{ce}\cu{g}&\zcn{N}{\A\mf}\ds\en%
\notes\slur{F}{G}d1\ibu0F1\qb0{^F}|\ds&\cup{g}\en%
\notes\tbu0\qb0{G}|\ds&\ccu{g}\en\bar%
\notes\zcn{d}{\A G7}\ibu1F3\qb1{`G}|\zcn{L}{\A\p}\ds&\isluru0m\ql{m}\en%
\notes\raise-2\Interligne\rlap\ds|\ibu0g{-1}\zqu{b}\qu{g}&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tbu1\qb1{G}|\tbu0\zqu{d}\qb0{f}&\tslur0k\cl{k}\en%
\notes\ds|\zqu{b}\qu{g}&\qp\en%
\notes\islurd0B\ibu2C1\qb2{B}|\hqsk&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tslur0D\tbu2\qb2{D}|\ds&\ds\en\bar%
\notes\lsf{!`G}\zqu{!G}\qu{!`G}|\ds&\beginmel\isluru0i\ql{i}\en%
\notes|\zqu{bd}\rq{g}\cu{f}&\hqsk\en%
\notes\lsf{!`H}\zqu{!H}\qu{!`H}|\ds&\endmel\tslur0k\cl{k}\en%
\notes|\zqu{bd}\rq{g}\cu{f}&\cu{g}\en%
\notes\lsf{!`I}\zqu{!I}\qu{!`I}|\ds&\beginmel\islurd0f\qu{f}\en%
\notes|\zqu{bd}\rq{g}\cu{f}&\multnoteskip\tinyvalue\tinynotesize
\Ibbu1gf1\qb1{g}\endmel\tqh1f\en\bar%
\notes\zcn{d}{\A C}\ibu1J4\zq{C}\qb1{J}|\ds&\tslur0e\qu{e}\en%
\notes\ds|\shake{m}\ibl0j{-1}\ql{j}&\en%
\notes\tbu1\zq{JL}\qb1{N}|\tbl0\qb0{i}&\ds\en%
\notes\ds|\ibu0j{-2}\qu{j}&\qp\en%
\notes\islurd0E\ibu2F1\qb2{E}|\qb0{g}&\en%
\notes\tslur0G\tbu2\qb2{G}|\tbu0\qb0{e}&\ds\en\alaligne%\bar%
%\addspace{-1\afterruleskip}% to create more space in the entire line
\notes\zcharnote{-18}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (pointB) at (2.41,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V7}}};
        \node (pointC) at (6.9,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
        \draw[red-undar,thick, line width=0.8mm] (0,0) -- (pointB) -- (pointC) -- (11.3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}\ibu1J1\qb1{C}|\ibu0d{0}\qu{c}&\qp\en%
\notes\ds|\qb0{e}&\en%
\notes\tbu1\zq{JL}\qb1{N}|\tbu0\qb0{d}&\ds\en%
\notes\ds|\shake{M}\ibu0d{-1}\qu{c}&\ds\en%
\notes\islurd0E\ibu2F1\qb2{E}|\qb0{b}&\cup{g}\en%
\notes\tslur0G\tbu2\qb2{G}|\tbu0\qb0{a}&\ccu{g}\en\bar%
\notes\zcn{d}{\A G7}\ibu1F3\qb1{`G}|\ibu0e{1}\qb0{N}&\isluru0m\ql{m}\en%
\notes\raise-2\Interligne\rlap\ds|\zqu{b}\qb0{g}&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tbu1\qb1{G}|\tbu0\zqu{d}\qb0{f}&\tslur0k\cl{k}\en%
\notes\ds|\zqu{b}\qu{g}&\qp\en%
\notes\islurd0B\ibu2C1\qb2{B}|\hqsk&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tslur0D\tbu2\qb2{D}|\ds&\ds\en\bar%
\notes\lsf{!`G}\zqu{!G}\qu{!`G}|\ds&\beginmel\isluru0i\ql{i}\en%
\notes|\zqu{bd}\rq{g}\cu{f}&\hqsk\en%
\notes\lsf{!`H}\zqu{!H}\qu{!`H}|\ds&\endmel\tslur0k\cl{k}\en%
\notes|\zqu{bd}\rq{g}\cu{f}&\cu{g}\en%
\notes\lsf{!`I}\zqu{!I}\qu{!`I}|\ds&\beginmel\islurd0f\qu{f}\en%
\notes|\zqu{bd}\rq{g}\cu{f}&\multnoteskip\tinyvalue\tinynotesize
\Ibbu1gf1\qb1{g}\endmel\tqh1f\en\bar%
\notes\zcn{d}{\A C}\ibu1J4\zq{C}\qb1{J}|\ds&\tslur0e\qu{e}\en%
\notes\ds|\ibl0j{-1}\ql{j}&\en%
\notes\tbu1\zq{JL}\qb1{N}|\tbl0\qb0{i}&\ds\en%
\notes\ds|\ibu0j{-2}\qu{j}&\qp\en%
\notes\islurd0E\ibu2E1\qb2{E}|\qb0{g}&\en%
\notes\tslur0G\tbu2\qb2{G}|\tbu0\qb0{e}&\ds\en\bar%
\notes\zqu{J}\qu{C}|\ibu0e{1}\qb0{c}&\cl{j}\en%
\notes|\tbu0\zqu{ce}\qb0{g}&\cl{i}\en%
\notes\lsf{E}\zqu{L}\qu{E}|\ds&\cl{j}\en%
\notes|\zqu{ce}\cu{g}&\usfz{k}\ql{k}\en%
\notes\ibu2K1\zqb2{M}\qb2{F}|\ds&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tbu2\zqb2{^M}\qb2{^F}|\ds&\cl{j}\en%\bar%
%\alaligne%
\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:


Your question isn't very clear (and really contains way more code that is needed.) How do you want it to change? The font parameter for the bar numbers is controlled by the macro \fontbarno so you could, for example do \renewcommand\fontbarno{\sffamily} to make it sans serif like your lyrics.

Solved: \def\writebarno{\the\barno}
\renewcommand\fontbarno{\A}

The font parameter for the bar numbers is controlled by the macro \fontbarno so you could, for example do \renewcommand\fontbarno{\sffamily} (or your \A font) to make it sans serif like your lyrics.
